# Expresiones Regulares Conservar solo el segundo set de parentesis (python)

Tags: python, regex

tengo el siguiente formato de informacion y necesito quedarme con todo lo que contenga el segundo parentesis (a veces el tercero )

**El texto que tengo es el siguiente:**

*AA(SONY)-AB(UP X898MD)-CA00-*

**necesito quedarme con:**

*UP X898MD*    (sin los parentesis)

Gracias!!!

Comment: Hola, puedes explicar mejor lo de `a veces el tercero`? Podrías poner varios ejemplos del texto de entrada y lo que necesitas encontrar?. Además, también deberías escribir aquí lo que comentas de que algunas líneas tienen *información agregada* y poner ejemplos

Comment: muchas gracias por la rta julio , ya lo pude solucionar , a veces los datos venian asi :
**ZA(000020)-ZB(000600)-ZC(000600)-ZD(000004)-AA(HP)-AB(D9L63A AC8)-CA00-NA00-**

y a veces asi:
**AA(HP)-AB(D9L63A AC8)-CA00-NA00-**
 entonces queria recorrer los parentesis , pero descubri que el dato que me sirve viene despues del AA   con eso lo solucione , muchas gracias igual por tu comentario
Saludos!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución rápida es obtener todos los textos entre paréntesis y escoger el segundo en orden:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile("\(([^)]*)\)")

elems = pat.findall(texto)

primero = elems[0] if len(elems) > 0 else ""
segundo = elems[1] if len(elems) > 1 else ""
tercero = elems[2] if len(elems) > 2 else ""
```

---

Para el caso de que queramos ignorar todo el texto anterior a `'AA'` para evitar problemas, se puede aplicar previamente un patrón que limpie el texto:

```py
import re

limpia = re.compile("^.*?AA")
pat = re.compile("\(([^)]*)\)")

texto_limpio = limpia.sub("", texto)
elems = pat.findall(texto_limpio)
```

Comment: excelente , para evitar errores , si quisiera quedarme con todo lo que viene despues de AA:

Porque algunas lineas tienen informacion agregada que me trae errores en el codigo   

ZA(000020)-ZB(000600)-ZC(000600)-ZD(000004)-AA(HP)-AB(D9L63A      AC8)-CA00-NA00-          

asique necesitaria quedarme con :
**AA(HP)-AB(D9L63A      AC8)-CA00-NA00-**
primero y luego utilizar el metodo de los parentesis
Gracias!!

Comment: Te respondo ampliando la respuesta...